# Error while converting JsonObject to JsonArray

Tags: java, json

Getting exception with the following code: org.glassfish.json.JsonStringImpl cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonArray

```
JsonObjectParser jop = new JsonObjectParser();
JsonObject jo = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("yAxisValue","Yvalue")
            .add("xAxisValue","Xvalue").build();
jo.getJsonArray("xAxisValue");
```

Note: using javax.json java API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating JSON Array by javax.json use following method.

```
JsonArray value = Json.createArrayBuilder()
     .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("type", "home")
         .add("number", "212 555-1234"))
     .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("type", "fax")
         .add("number", "646 555-4567"))
     .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is the following

```
.add("xAxisValue","Xvalue")
```

the statement above is not to create a `json array`, `the json string` you created is the following

```
{ 
  "yAxisValue":"Yvalue",
  "xAxisValue":"Xvalue"
}
```

not

```
{ 
  "yAxisValue":"Yvalue",
  "xAxisValue":["Xvalue"]
}
```

you should use the function `add("key",Json.createArrayBuilder(...))`

hope that helped